# New Language Compiler, LLVM Backend and Xcode 7.x

Tags: xcode, macos, llvm

Environment - El Capitan, Xcode 7.x, clang (Apple LLVM version 7.0.2)

Goal - Write a new language compiler that emits LLVM IR to be consumed by LLVM to emit machine code.

Question: With Xcode installed it appears that not all LLVM tools that I need for my bootstrap compiler tool chain are installed. What is easiest way to install said tools without breaking the Xcode setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: it's not connected with XCode at all. Simply download the relevant LLVM release, compile it and you'll have all the libraries and development tools. No XCode is involved.

Comment: I will give it a whirl and test this out, thanks. After testing I will happily come back and accept this. Thanks